# Customer count map (Google maps?)

Tags: google-maps

I have a two column list consisting of a US zipcode and a count (number of customers in this case). I want to put this data onto a map.  Would Google maps API be a good fit for this?

It seems like this would be a common enough type of problem to already have an existing (preferably Java based) solution without having to re-invent the wheel.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer: Google Fusion Tables
http://tables.googlelabs.com/Home

Comment: This link is dead. Is there an updated way to do this?